# Function couldn't resolved Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to build an NDK project but I am facing an error. The `reverse` function couldn't be resolved in a project using JNI with NDK Android, which you can see in the attached image.

[image]

I have added the path in project properties at path and symbols section --->see screenshot for this too.

[image]

Comment: Eclipse bug, there is no clear way to fix it. Sometimes when you reindex, the problem is gone temporarily but it will haunt you back again after sometime. I switched to Visual Studio using Nvidia NSight Tools just because of it, and native debugging was not working also. Eclipse is really painful when it comes to NDK.

Comment: For various workarounds that may or may not work, check out this thread: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33788