# fatal error: libavcodec/avcodec.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

[image]

The tooltip is over the line

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
```

I'm new to JNI development. After managing to compile FFMPEG i fail to be able to use it on a project.

On the screenshot you can see that the folder with the libs and includes is referenced under includes (via Project/properties/C/C++ general/paths and symbols)

To me it looks like it should find it but i get the error.

What extra place do i have to specify this folder for the build to work?

Edit : contents of Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := FFMpegTest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := FFMpegTest.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

Thanks

Comment: Is that an eclipse IDE error, or a compile error?  If IDE error, try rebuilding your index.

Comment: Seems like an IDE error, but "clear project" + "build project" doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Right click on your project, select Index -> Rebuild.

Comment: Thanks! but it didn't work. My Android.mk looks like this:

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := FFMpegTest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := FFMpegTest.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil
 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829031/function-couldnt-resolved-android-ndk